# Angular serve library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-library

In latest versions of Angular cli, we can use `ng g library lib-name` command to create library. As mentioned in the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/cli/serve) :

```
ng serve <project>
```

And:

```
<project>   The name of the project to build. Can be an app or a library.
```

So, we can serve **library**. But when I serve I get the following errors:

```
Project 'ngx-tab-component' does not support the 'serve' target.
Error: Project 'ngx-tab-component' does not support the 'serve' target.
at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\vahidnajafi\angular\ngx-tab-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:53:19)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Comment: I can't imagine a context where it would make sense to serve a library. It's not an application, it's a library. You import a library into an application that you later serve. How are you expecting this to work?

Comment: @R.Richards Actually I didn't expect it. But in the docs is mentioned about serving project (and project can be a library). And if there will be no livereload for library, that would be very difficult to develop.

Comment: Good points. It is odd that the tools even mentions it if it doesn't do anything. Maybe this is meant for some *future* functionality we don't know about yet. :)

Comment: So how can I test my library? Should I serve application in each change of library? (That's really a pain)

Comment: Have you tried serving the application that uses the library, then make some change to the library to see if `ng serve` recompiles? I have not tried that, but it would be nice it that worked.

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Comment: @R.Richards Please see my answer. I found a solution for this.

Comment: @R.Richards, that's exactly how it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project where you generate your library in serves as a host to debug and test it.

Simply import your library in your host application module, make sure all dependencies are available and serve the host application. All changes you make inside your library are directly live reloaded into your host application.

**Note:** <s>You have to import `projects/foo-lib/src/public_api`, not 'dist/foo-lib' though</s>

Use your official library name, for example `@foo/foo-library`, angular will find it in the correct location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately serving application doesn't make any sense for changing code in library.

Comment: sure it makes sense, every change in your library is reflected in the host application. you only need `ng serve`, not `ng build foo --watch` like you suggested.

Comment: you have to import 'projects/foo-lib/src/public_api' or 'projects/foo-lib', not 'dist/foo-lib' though

Comment: Yes. you are completely right. Thank you. I'm going to accept this answer. So please add your last comment to the answer. That was the point.

Comment: Your note is incorrect. You should import libraries through your dist folder. Same as you would import built libraries installed through npm so should you first build your library and then import it. https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5 for reference.

Comment: @StephenVerbist, fixed it

Comment: @MarkusDresch What overall project structure do you have?
Currently I'm storing my libraries in NPM and they exist separately from host component. So I came with an idea to create some demo host project and place it in the same folder to test and debug libraries in browser.
My project structure now is
> project
>> dist
>> packages
>> test
>> angular.json
>> package.json
>> ...

Answer (score 8):

You can update path in main `tsconfig.json` from

```
"paths": {
  "library": {
    "dist/library"
  }
}
```

to

```
"paths": {
  "library": {
    "projects/library/src/public-api"
  }
}
```

Then you don't need to start separate build for your library and rebuild also works.

Comment: All the `npm link` and `wait-for` huzzle gone. Nice!

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 6):

<s>Finally found the solution.</s>

First I watch to built version of library by following (provided from **Angular Cli 6.2**):

```
ng build foo-lib --watch
```

Then I serve application simply by:

```
ng serve
```

And I import the module from `dist` directory (because I can watch to built version):

```
import { FooLibModule } from 'dist/foo-lib';
```

Then every change in my library, cause change to the build version, and my application can reload properly.

It seems the process is a bit complicated.

Comment: you only need `ng serve` and import from project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers suggests to `ng build mylib --watch` your library and then `ng serve` but I feels a bit clunky. I want something to run by simply doing `ng serve` and nothing else.

Here is the solution I came up with it works fine in Angular 15 (with multi project workspace).

```
- libs/common-lib
- projects/firstApp
- projects/secondApp
- tsconfig.json
```

Basically, I had to modify `tsconfig.json` in the root of the project.

**From:**

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "common-lib": [
        "dist/common-lib",
      ]
    },
```

**To:**

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "common-lib": [
        "libs/common-lib/src/public-api",
      ]
    },
```