# How can I make "ng serve" wait for "ng build" to finish?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I started working on a company's project, and I've been told that to start the local development server I must first run the command:
`"package:serve": "ng build project-name --watch"`
and then:
`"start": "ng serve"`

The problem in doing so, is that `ng serve` starts reloading as soon as `ng build` starts recompiling, so after each file change it refreshes the browser ~3 times and often doesn't show the new changes in the browser window until a 4th (manual) refresh.

Now as you can see, this is **VERY** uncomfortable to use.
I wish that ng serve would refresh only 1 time, after the build is done.

#### Is there a better way, to run `ng build` and `ng serve` concurrently?

Comment: Check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Comment: @PranoySarkar This seemed promising, but it starts `ng serve` before `ng build` has compiled, so it crashes immedeately, and only `ng build --watch` is left running.

The command I tried: `concurrently -n "package,serve" "npm run package:serve" "npm run start"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it thanks to this other question:
[Angular serve library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146811/angular-serve-library)

I edited my `tsconfig.json` with the correct path to the library (not /dist/)

changed

```
    "paths": {
      "my-lib": [
        "dist/my-lib"
      ],
      ...
```

to

```
    "paths": {
      "my-lib": [
        "projects/my-lib/src/public-api"
      ],
      ...
```

Now I can use only `ng serve` and everything works correctly.